# How to format a time (not a date) using Luxon?

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs, luxon

I need to convert backend-fetched data "17:00" to "5pm". Using `moment` I just do:

```
moment('17:00', ['HH']).format('h:mma')
```

How to achieve the same thing with `Luxon`? While `moment` allows to format times directly, it seems `Luxon`'s [format functions](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimehour) require a date (which I don't have).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you use today's date with the BE specified hours?

Answer (score 5):

```js
DateTime.fromISO('17:00').toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_SIMPLE)    // 5:00 PM
DateTime.fromISO('17:00').toFormat('h:mma')                       // 5:00PM
DateTime.fromISO('17:00').toFormat('h:mm a')                      // 5:00 PM
```

couldn't figure out how to make meridiem lowercase though
https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/224

**EDIT** if want in lowercase can do something like this

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
 
const dt = DateTime.fromISO('17:00')
const meridiem = (dt.hour > 11) ? 'p' : 'a'
const final =  `${dt.toFormat('h:mm')}${meridiem}m`

console.log(final)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE** as [Lukas H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11637956/lukas-h) mentioned in the comments an easier approach would be to use `.toLowerCase()`

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

const dt = DateTime.fromISO('17:00')
const final =  dt.toFormat('h:mma').toLowerCase()

console.log(final)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you want `am` and `pm` to be lowercase, the easiest way would be to just use `.toLowerCase()`, as `.toFormat()` returns a string.

`DateTime.fromISO('17:00').toFormat('h:mma').toLowerCase() // 5:00pm`

Comment: @LukasH. nice catch. I updated the answer